# Can someone demonstrate a variable approximation to echo final variable results more concisely

Tags: php, floating-point

Can anyone provide an alternative answer to my variable summations without it being a floating point decimal result with the possibility of displaying the final result as in an interger value. Whole numbers to be exact.

With every variable passing results in decimal notation, the final value is larger than the actual pen to paper I get using calculator.

This yeld s `echo $ter`resulting in float value 43402777.777778. It should be more in the lines of 42,849,000 instead of the former, the latter value is my pen and paper. The problem is outputting final value to be non scientific notation. I need in straight interger value.

```
$tan = 100000;
$g = 30;
$epp = 12;
$days = 365;
$bpe = 4;
$pp = 300;

$apg = $tan / $g; 
$epg = $apg / $bpe;
$ppg = $epg / $epp;
$ypr = $ppg * $pp;
$tep = $ppg * $g;
$ter = $ypr * $tep;

echo $ter;
```

Comment: Can you explain further with an example?

Comment: Please explain your question further by including your current code, examples of what you'd like the result to be and examples of your current observations (ie, what your code currently does)

Comment: You mean scientific?

Comment: any calculator really, just not programming scripted

Comment: please if you are here to judge, use discretion.

Answer (score 2):

As is typical in computer science, [floating-point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) comes with its own set of problems.

Libraries are generally available for more precision. PHP offers the [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/book.bc.php) functions.

Your example can be altered to use this...

```
$tan = 100000;
$g = 30;
$epp = 12;
$days = 365;
$bpe = 4;
$pp = 300;

$apg = bcdiv($tan, $g); 
$epg = bcdiv($apg, $bpe);
$ppg = bcdiv($epg, $epp);
$ypr = bcmul($ppg, $pp);
$tep = bcmul($ppg, $g);
$ter = bcmul($ypr, $tep);
echo '$ter: ', $ter, PHP_EOL; // 42849000
echo 'Formatted: ', number_format($ter), PHP_EOL; // 42,849,000
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/vlRaS